# How to delete a file with a file size of 0 along with other two files of same name except first two characters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I have three files in a folder.

For example:

```
IX20150912.dat
TX20150912.dat
PY20150912.dat
```

I need to delete all these three files if any of the file has a file size of 0 bytes using a Windows batch file.

How can this be done?

Comment: This site expects that you search, research and write your own code, coming here for assistance if your code fails to do that which was expected of it. Asking somebody else to do your coding for you is rude and off topic. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46276370/edit) your question to include your code and explain where it fails to perform to expectations.

Comment: i don't know anything about cmd. I tried even but failed all the times and wasn't even sure whether I was working in the right direction. And, was given the ultimatum by heads .So, stop judging before knowing the situations. BTW, Thanks!

Comment: No. That could have been avoided if you had given us all of the information up front. Also, if you had included some of the things you tried that didn't work, you wouldn't have gotten downvoted. We just need to be reassured that you tried *something*. You'd be surprised by the number of people who start out simply by asking a question.

Comment: Thanks I got the result.

Comment: Please regard that your situation, your deadlines and your (poor) project planning is only your problem, but not ours! [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) is a question and answer site for programming-related questions, no more, no less; it is not a site for reaching your particular milestones and/or completing your tasks! Please keep this in mind when asking further questions! Thank you! By the way, please consider to read the [tour] and learn [ask]...

Comment: I don't know what's the problem with the people? If you all don't want to answer then don't but please stop commenting useless and unnecessary things just to gain some points!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Please do some work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a batch file search for files `0kb`, then remove the first 2 characters, then find all files with the same name, excluding the first two characters and delete them.

> Example.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*) do if %%~zF==0 (
set old=%%F
set new=!old:~2!
echo del /Q "??!new!"
)
```

Note!! I am echoing the delete here only, you need to remove echo in order to actually delete the files, **BUT** first test with echo before removing it to ensure you are deleting the correct files.

Comment: @richa That is concerning.. :) Do your managers think you know batch? Perhaps you should consider learning batch, especially if you work in a windows environment.

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks